# Does anyone see this expression to get data in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```py
nums_frames = dataset['n_frames'][()]
```

Here use `[()]` to get the data. i don't understand, i haven't seen this kind of usage in python before.
if anyone knows that, could you please explain the usage and scenerio?

Comment: Where did you see this? In what context?

Comment: yesyes, that makes sense. if dataset['n_frames'] is a dict, and then the empty tuple is the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since tuples are hashable, they can be used as dict keys. That includes the empty tuple:

```
d = {
    (): 'a'
}

print(d[()])
```

This outputs:

```
a
```